# How does the increment operator work on an Integer instance if Java doesn't support operator overloading?

Tags: java, oop, operator-overloading, increment

I read that Java does not support operator overloading. Then it made me wonder how you can use the increment operator on an instance of the Integer class.

```
Integer number = new Integer(10);
System.out.println(++number);
```

The above code compiles fine, without error. But let's say I made my own class, with only one member variable (an integer), and tried to use the increment operator. It would give me a compiler error. Why is this?

Comment: Answer to the question in the title: that operator is defined for Integer. Answer to the question at the end of your post: because that operator is not defined for your class (and can't be because operator overloading is not allowed).

Comment: Integers are immutable. Are you sure it is incrementing `number` rather than just converting it to an `int` and showing `++int`? Print `number` after your preincrement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the sequence of operations that are performed when you call the increment operator on an `Integer` object:

1. `Integer` wrapper object is unboxed to an `int` primitive (using the `intValue()` method).
2. Primitive is incremented.
3. Incremented primitive is autoboxed to an `Integer` wrapper object.

So, in effect, the operator is actually applied to an `int` primitive, and not to an object. This behavior is only defined for objects of the primitive wrapper classes, and there is no way to make your own classes behave in a similar way.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more info about autoboxing and unboxing.